# Python Tkinter Currency Calculator Float Multiplied by RadioButton var

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, floating-point, radio-button

I'm making a Currency Converter and received issues trying to return a value (from radio buttons) multiplied by the users input. toNZD and fromNZD are triggered from the drop down menu's, which will be changed soon. Thanks for anyone's input.

```
from tkinter import *
mGui = Tk()

number=0
currency=StringVar()
tester=0

def fromNZD():
    global tester
    currencySelect=currency.get()
    if currencySelect ==1:
        tester = 0.4 #eg's
    elif currencySelect ==2:
        tester= 1.2 #eg's

    userInput=number.get()
    final=(float(userInput)*(tester))#<-------
    mlabel2=Label(mGui,text='${0:.2f}!'.format(final)).pack()


def toNZD():
    userInput2=number.get()
    userInput2=(float(userInput2)/0.6)
    mlabel3=Label(mGui,text='${0:.2f}!'.format(userInput2)).pack()

def terminate():
    global mGui
    mGui.destroy()


menu = Menu(mGui)
mGui.config(menu=menu)

tofrom = StringVar(mGui)
tofrom.set("To") #initial value

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Currency Settings", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="From NZD", command=fromNZD)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="To NZD", command=toNZD)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=terminate)

mlabel = Label(text='Currency Calculator',bg="orange red", fg='gray20',font=("Century Gothic",20))
mlabel.pack(fill=X)

Radiobutton(mGui, text="GBP", variable=currency, value=1, indicatoron=0).pack()
Radiobutton(mGui, text="USD", variable=currency, value=2, indicatoron=0).pack()


number=Entry(mGui,textvariable=number)
number.pack(pady=8)

mGui.configure(background='deepskyblue3')
mGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
mGui.title('Currency Converter')
mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I'm making a Currency Converter and received issues"_ - what issues have you received? Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: The code seems to work. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting any errors, but when I try to convert a currency from NZD it returns $0.00. I would like it to output the input multiplied by the tester ~ 0.4 or 1.2.

Comment: A printscreen of what I am talking about: http://prntscr.com/azndn6

Apologies for the misleading title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currency` is a `StringVar()` so `currency.get()` returns a `string`. You are trying to compare `currencySelect` with an integer(1 or 2) in your `fromNZD()` method. Hence both comparisons fail and `tester` variable doesn't change(still it is 0) and since `tester = 0`, multiplication results 0.

You can convert `currency.get()` to an integer

```
currencySelect= int(currency.get())
```

or compare `currencySelect` with string values(`"1"`, `"2"` etc.).

```
currencySelect=currency.get()
    if currencySelect == "1":
        tester = 0.4 #eg's
    elif currencySelect == "2":
        tester= 1.2 #eg's
```

Also, it'll be better to include an `else` statement just in case to see something went wrong. Maybe printing an error or pop-up message.